# Facebook API. Change video thumbnail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When you upload a video to facebook, it lets you specify a thumbnail you want to use out of the 10 it generates and offers you (In the edit settings). Is there a way to upload a video and have it change the thumbnail to one of their randomly generated thumbnails using the api instead of having to do it manually?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly tell Facebook to select one of those default thumbnails.

You can query the [api_url]/v2.3/[video_id]/thumbnails edge which gives you the 10 thumbnails that Facebook has extracted from the video, and then set one of those as the video thumb using the same edge yourself.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/thumbnails/